# How to change Rider's Rename modal dimensions

Tags: c#, rider

I'm using Rider on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) and I'm having strange issue when using rename action. Modal that is being opened by default hides the text that I'm supposed to update. The only way to make it look as expected is to manually change the size of the modal using mouse, but that's inconvenient. Does anyone know how to define the modal dimensions?

I found workaround - changing font size to smaller one, but this affects it everywhere (Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Appearance).

Current:

[image]

Expected:

[image]